# Whats the best way to convert this table into a table with the time as rows?

Tags: r

I downloaded some data form eurostat. The format of the data is not that useful to me. It is like this:

| TIME | GEO | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | Belgium | 63.5 |
| 2012 | Belgium | 64.6 |
| ... |  |  |
| 2018 | Belgium | 63.4 |
| 2019 | Belgium | 62.4 |
| 2010 | Bulgaria | 65.0 |
| 2011 | Bulgaria | 64.0 |
| ... |  |  |
| 2019 | Bulgaria | 66.3 |
| 2010 | Czechia | 63.3 |
| 2011 | Czechia | 62.9 |
| ... |  |  |

**What is the right r command to convert it in a format like this: ?**

| GEO | 2010 | 2011 | ... | 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Belgium | 63.5 | 64.6 | ... | 62.4 |
| Bulgaria | 65.0 | ... | ... | 66.3 |
| Czechia | 63.3 | ... | ... | ... |

I have the data as .csv.
With group by and split I did not reach my goal.
I want to plot the data to time and than compare it to other datasets I already have in this format.

Comment: `reshape:: cast(data[,-1],GEO~TIME,mean)`

Comment: I strongly urge you not to transform the data as you request. In its present state, the data set is tidy. In your proposed form, it is not. (Because your new column names contain information: the year. R  - and not just the tidyverse - works best with tidy data. With tidy data, your code will almost certainly be more robust, more readable and shorter.  That’s not to say you should _present_ your data in tidy format. Often, presentation looks better in other layouts. But for _analysis_, your life will be easier if your data is tidy.

Comment: @Limey how would you then plot the value over time for each country or all in one plot each with a individual line?

Comment: To answer OP's question in comment: Using the tidyverse, something like `df %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=TIME, y=VALUE, colour=GEO))`.  Note that this code is compact, easily readable and robust with respect to the addition of new `GEO`s or `TIME`s. Transformed as per OP's request, equivalent code is not robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINAL update: after correcting the data by OP, (removed prior answer):

```
df %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(TIME , VALUE) %>% 
  group_by(TIME) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = TIME, values_from = VALUE, 
              values_fill = 0)
```

output:

```
  GEO      `2010` `2011` `2012` `2018` `2019`
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Czechia    63.3   62.9    0      0      0  
2 Bulgaria   65     64      0      0     66.3
3 Belgium     0     63.5   64.6   63.4   62.4
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(TIME = c(2011L, 2012L, 2018L, 2019L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2019L, 2010L, 2011L), GEO = c("Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Bulgaria", "Czechia", "Czechia"
), VALUE = c(63.5, 64.6, 63.4, 62.4, 65, 64, 66.3, 63.3, 62.9
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: try with `dplyr::select`: like `df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-ID) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(TIME, VALUE) %>% 
  group_by(TIME) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = TIME, values_from = VALUE) `

Comment: Error in pivot_wider(., names_from = TIME, values_from = VALUE, values_fill = 0) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

again an error tried to add values_fill = 0 but didn´t helped

Comment: Please see my update. If it fails. Update `tidyverse`.

Comment: OK. Please see my update!